# Request Parameter in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using express.js and I am trying to fetch the request parameter using the following code.

```
app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.params[0]);
  console.log(req.params.id);
  res.render('/public/index.html');
});
```

My url looks like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/?id=34.
```

I am not getting the request parameter. I tried all possibilities.

Answer (score 29):

You need to reference [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query)

[`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params) is for params embedded in the URL path.

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks for the edit, I was mobile while writing this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

> req.param('id')

It will fetch path,body and query params for you.

Comment: This is a deprecated method. Use `req.params` (POST) or `req.query` (GET) now.